# Pandas dataframe call for a previous row from inside a loop gives me wrong(?) values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

i'm trying to do some recursive calculation that require to perform an operation in row i with the row i-1
I don't know why but I can't make it work with the `iloc[i-1]` or `.shift()` functions.

I define a function:

```
import pandas as pd


def myfunction(df):
    #getting the length of the table for the loop:
    code_len = df.shape[0]
    print(df)
    creating new output df
    dnl = df
    #this loop is taking the i'th row and subtract from it the i-1'th row
    for i in range(1, code_len):
        print(i)
        dnl.iloc[i] = (df.iloc[i] - df.iloc[i-1])
    droping the first row because there is now subtraction there
    dnl = dnl.drop(0)
    print(dnl)
    return dnl
```

when i call this function :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(3, 4), columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])
something = myfunction(csv_in)
```

the first print output of the input df is

```
    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
```

each row is different by 4 from the one before it

inside the loop i try to do a subtraction between two rows, i and i-1 but it doesn't give me the desired result

```
   0  1  2  3
1  4  4  4  4
2  4  5  6  7
3  8  8  8  8
```

I also tried with `.shift()`

```
def myfunction(df):
    code_len = df.shape[0]
    print(df.tail())
    dnl = df
    for i in range(1, code_len):
        print(i)
        dnl.iloc[i] = (df.iloc[i] - df.shift().iloc[i])
    dnl = dnl.drop(0)
    print(dnl)
    return dnl
```

but I get the same result.
isn't i-1 supposed to work here? what am I missing?

i expect to get:

```
   0  1  2  3
1  4  4  4  4
2  4  4  4  4
3  4  4  4  4
```

thanks

Comment: Why don't you provide a minimal reproducible example (just a few rows, no "...") with the matching expected output, and explain your logic

Comment: @mozway thank you, I have edited my post with a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you copy dnl = df and change dnl, those changes are reflected in the original dataframe. Use copy(), description [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).

```
dnl = df.copy()
```